# How to resize a base64 image to occupy less?

Tags: android, base64, resize

I have an Bitmap image hat i convert to base64, but I want that the image to occupy less because I want to upload that image to a database and it needs to be less than a mb.

```
 Convert from Bitmap to base 64:  

 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    final String imagenPlanta = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it smaller you have to get rid of information. Do something like JPEG, it will focus on removing information that is less relevant, many times a JPEG image looks just fine but is like 10 times smaller.